# latex3 / expl3 equivalent of \raisebox with lenght expression

Tags: expl3

I am trying to learn expl3 by re-implementing some macros and little packages
to take advantage of it.

I am now wondering if there is a more latex3-ish way of doing something like

```
\raisebox{-\height+\baselineskip}{#1}
```

which requires `calc`, given that the ability to make computations on dimensions should be present in `expl3`.

Comment: `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip\relax}{#1}`,  and as `expl3` requires e-TeX.... Here is a private joke, already 20 years ago, physicists were saying that  if a "supersymmetric particle"  was discovered at CERN (i.e. a particle whose mass is in expected range), then this would "prove" String Theory, because String Theory implements supersymmetry. Based on this physicist reasoning, my remark is expl3 coding.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible redefinition, using a key-value interface instead of multiple optional argument for setting the final height and depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xraisebox}{O{}mm}
 {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { x/raisebox }
   {
    height=,
    depth=,
    #1
   }
  \x_raisebox:nn { #2 } { #3 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { x/raisebox }
 {
  height .tl_set:N = \l__x_raisebox_ht_tl,
  depth  .tl_set:N = \l__x_raisebox_dp_tl,
 }

\box_new:N \l__x_raisebox_in_box
\box_new:N \l__x_raisebox_out_box
\dim_new:N \l__x_raisebox_height_dim
\dim_new:N \l__x_raisebox_depth_dim
\dim_new:N \l__x_raisebox_totalheight_dim
\dim_new:N \l__x_raisebox_width_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \x_raisebox:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__x_raisebox_in_box { #2 }
  \cs_set_eq:NN \height \l__x_raisebox_height_dim
  \cs_set_eq:NN \depth \l__x_raisebox_depth_dim
  \cs_set_eq:NN \totalheight \l__x_raisebox_totalheight_dim
  \cs_set_eq:NN \width \l__x_raisebox_width_dim
  \dim_set:Nn \l__x_raisebox_height_dim { \box_ht:N \l__x_raisebox_in_box }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__x_raisebox_depth_dim { \box_dp:N \l__x_raisebox_in_box }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__x_raisebox_totalheight_dim { \height+\depth }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__x_raisebox_width_dim { \box_wd:N \l__x_raisebox_in_box }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__x_raisebox_out_box
   {
    \box_move_up:nn { #1 } { \box_use_drop:N \l__x_raisebox_in_box }
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__x_raisebox_ht_tl
   {
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l__x_raisebox_out_box { \dim_eval:n { \l__x_raisebox_ht_tl } }
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__x_raisebox_dp_tl
   {
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l__x_raisebox_out_box { \dim_eval:n { \l__x_raisebox_dp_tl } }
   }
  \box_use_drop:N \l__x_raisebox_out_box
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

x\raisebox{3pt}{y\raisebox{3pt}{z}}

x\xraisebox{3pt}{y\xraisebox{3pt}{z}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\fbox{\xraisebox{3pt}{y}}

\fbox{x\xraisebox{3pt}{y\xraisebox{3pt}{z}}}
\fbox{x\xraisebox{3pt}{y\xraisebox[height=0pt]{3pt}{z}}}
\fbox{x\xraisebox{3pt}{y\xraisebox[height=3pt+0.5\height]{3pt}{z}}}

\fbox{x\xraisebox{-3pt}{y\xraisebox{-3pt}{z}}}
\fbox{x\xraisebox{-3pt}{y\xraisebox[depth=0pt]{-3pt}{z}}}
\fbox{x\xraisebox{-3pt}{y\xraisebox[depth=20pt]{-3pt}{z}}}

\end{document}
```

The commands `\height`, `\depth`, `\totalheight` and `\width` are set locally to equate some internal dimensions. Each box is built inside a group to allow nesting.

[image]

Comment: Would using coffins help provide an alternate solution?

Comment: @Callegar Most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *coffins* can help, for instance, the following function can provide different types of vertical alignment:

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \Vadj } { O{m} m }
  {
    % Beware, this gets out of math mode, so if you are in math mode, you need
    % to re-enter it.
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { #2 }
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        { t }
          {
            \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_coffin {l}{H}{0pt}
              { -\coffin_ht:N \l_tmpa_coffin }
          }
        { m }
          {
            \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_coffin {l}{H}{0pt}
              { -0.5\coffin_ht:N \l_tmpa_coffin + 0.5\coffin_dp:N
                \l_tmpa_coffin }
          }
        { b }
          {
            \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_coffin {l}{H}{0pt}
              { \coffin_dp:N \l_tmpa_coffin }
          }
      }
  }
```

Just like `\risebox`, this gets you out of math mode, so if you are in math mode, you need to re-enter it.

It is not 100% clear if this is proper `expl3` code, as I have just started learning it, but it seems to do the job.